# Subprocess includes problematic quotation marks in Python 3.7+

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, python-3.7, python-3.8

### The Problem

I'm experiencing errors with the Python3 [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. Subprocess is surrounding some important positional arguments I give it with unicode quotation marks which causes the linux command **find** to fail.

Has anyone else had this problem? I'm basically trying to figure out if its a misconfiguration on my end or if I should post it as an issue for the subprocess team. I'm sure I could work around it in my code, but it just seemed like a bug that should get squashed.

**test.py**

```py
import subprocess
p = subprocess.run(['find', '/.snapshots/*/snapshot', '-maxdepth', '0', '-type', 'd' ], capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8')
print(p)
```

**test.py result**

```py
CompletedProcess(
  args=['find', '/.snapshots/*/snapshot', '-maxdepth', '0', '-type', 'd'], 
  returncode=1,
  stdout='',
  stderr='find: ‘/.snapshots/*/snapshot’: No such file or directory\n'
)
```

### My Take

It looks to me like subprocess is forcing find to surround my path string with unicode quotation marks and that bash is just registering those quotation marks as just another character as the find command always does.

**Intended command**

```sh
user@mine:$ find /.snapshots/*/snapshot/ -maxdepth 0 -type d
/.snapshots/1/snapshot/
/.snapshots/2/snapshot/
/.snapshots/3/snapshot/
```

**Command it seems to be running**

```sh
user@mine:$ find ‘/.snapshots/*/snapshot’ -maxdepth 0 -type d
find: ‘‘/.snapshots/*/snapshot\’’: No such file or directory
```

The fact that the quotation marks are unicode is **not** the problem. With the find command (at least in my experience with the versions I've used) you just don't want to pass the path surrounded by quotation marks of any kind. Even if there is a workaround that makes this behavior work for the find command, it still seems like a problem waiting for the next bash program that doesn't expect quotation marks.

**Another failed find command**

```sh
user@mine:$ find '/.snapshots/*/snapshot' -maxdepth 0 -type d
find: '/.snapshots/*/snapshot': No such file or directory
```

### System Details

When I first ran into this problem, I was running Python 3.7.4. I updated to see if there was a fix, so I'm now running python 3.8.1. I'm running on Arch Linux so I'm expecting this could be the typical pains of using software still in testing.

Comment: Globs and quotes are a shell thing. No shell is involved here.

Comment: The quotes aren't the problem; they're just part of the error message after `find` has already failed. The problem is that the glob isn't being expanded, because you aren't using the shell to run the command, and `/.snapshots/*/snapshot` is taken literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a glob (which the shell is intended to expand *before* `find` runs), use the following:

```
p = subprocess.run(['find', '/.snapshots/', '-path', '*/snapshot', '-maxdepth', '2', '-type', 'd' ], capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

The argument to `-path` is a pattern that is meant for `find` itself to use match against any file found under `/.snapshots`.